# Personalized videos

Tags: video

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I'm wanting to create a personalized video where a person's name is inserted dynamically. I know there are services out there like vidyard and idomoo that will put a person's name on a mug or a piece of paper, but would like to figure out how to make my own. Any help and direction is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with After Effects and scripting. After Effects has a javascript-based API called [extendscript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/aftereffects.html) that allows you to programatically create compositions - which can be as complex as you like, using pre-shot and/or generated footage, and effects. Extendscript means that AE can be run from the command line–on a server for instance.

You can either write the scripts yourself if your JS skills are good and you don't mind learning the quirks of the API, you could find a developer, or there are 3rd party frameworks that let you automate things like this - the downside is that they are relatively pricey: have a look at [dataclay](http://dataclay.com/) for instance. Work out what is the best ROI for you.